# How do you change a user's profile picture on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, profile, image

How do you change someone's Facebook profile picture to an image saved on my server using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There is not an API for this.

Comment: then is there a way to do it using JavaScript or something like that. I have seen other people do it but haven't been able to get the help to reproduce it.

Comment: I saw some apps that just give user instructions on how to make picture generated to their album as their profile/cover picture. Not using some api like that, just the flow of it. Example are those apps that make cover photos on timeline.

Comment: No, there is no way for an app to change a user's profile pic.